# Should I make a class member field const if it's only going to be assigned once in the body of the class?

Tags: c++

Is putting a const when defining a class member variable a good idea if you know it'll only be assigned once?

```
class A{

  public:
     A(){
       _varA = someFunc();
       _varB = someFunc2();
     };     

  private:
    const std::string _varA; //is putting const here a good practice?
    const std::string _varB; //is putting const here a good practice?
}
```

Comment: You'd have to initialize `_varA` and `_varB` in the member initializer list, not the body the constructor. This is still probably not worth it compared to making them non-`const` but not writing any publically visible methods that allow changing `_varA` and `_varB`. For instance, do you want `A` instances to be assignable?

Comment: You cannot assign to a `const` object. The two assignments in the sample code are illegal. You initialize `const` members (and all members, for that matter) in the initializer list.

Comment: `const` members make it overly difficult to assign instances of the class. I usually find it better to just make the member `private` and not modify it.

Comment: @NathanPierson well I will need to initialize an instance of `A` of course, like `auto myInstance = A();` Why is that a problem?>

Comment: `auto myInstance = A();` works because it is initialization rather than assignment, but `myInstance1 = myinstance2;` is not trivial and probably not a good idea. What if both instances have a different value for `_varA`? It can't be changed after initialization making the assignment questionable.

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code?  Did you notice that it won't compile?  Making them `const` means you cannot even assign to them once.  They can only be initialized.

Comment: @user1008636 -- Nathan Pierson said **assignable**; that's different from constructible. `const` members mean that without going through some gymnastics you can't write `A a; A b; a = b;`. Sure, `A a; A b = a;` is okay; that's construction, not assignment.

Comment: @PeteBecker but if i declare something as const as a class member field without initializing it. What value does it have? If it has NO value, why can't I assign it later? eg: `const std::string myString;` This has no value assigned. So I'm not 'changing' it by assigning it later (not via initializer list).

Comment: @user1008636 -- `_varA = someFunc();` does **not** initialize `_varA`. It **assigns** to it, which is why it's illegal if `_varA` is `const`. You initialize it in the initializer list: `A() : _varA(someFunc()), _varB(someFunc2()) {}`. If you don't explicitly initialize it it will be default initialized; if it can't be default initialized the code is illegal.